# MPMoviePlayerController hide volume slider

Tags: ios, object, mpmovieplayercontroller

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to hide the volume slider while playing a video in fullscreen mode but retaining the standard controls such as play/pause, previous/next etc

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a suggestion, totally untested :)

```
for (UIView *view in [volumeSlider subviews]) {
      if ([[view isKindOfClass:[MPVolumeSlider class]]) {
        [view setHidden:YES];
  }
}
```

Comment: Couldnt get it to work but i have just pushed back on the clients request. Thanks for the suggestion