# Hide volume bar in movie player

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer, mpvolumeview

How can I hide the volume bar in movie player and keep the other controls are appear (play, forward ... ) ? I want to show some videos that haven't any sounds, so the volume bar is totally will be useless.

can I do this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Set the  `controlStyle` of the `MPMoviePlayer` to `MPMovieControlStyleNone`.

```
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
```

But this will hide all the controls from the view.

After setting to `MPMovieControlStyleNone`, if you want to display the play/pause option and seek bar, You need to add custom controls.
(I did it before, I used slider as seek bar and and placed it in a `UIToolBar` along with a Tool bar button . Button is for play/pause option)

> **MPMovieControlStyle**
>
> Constants describing the style of the playback controls.
>
> enum {    MPMovieControlStyleNone,    MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded,
>   MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen,    MPMovieControlStyleDefault =
>   MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen }; typedef NSInteger
>   MPMovieControlStyle;
>
> **Constants**
>
> MPMovieControlStyleNone
>
> ```
> No controls are displayed.
>
> Available in iOS 3.2 and later.
>
> Declared in MPMoviePlayerController.h.
> ```
>
> MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded
>
> ```
> Controls for an embedded view are displayed. The controls include a start/pause button, a scrubber bar, and a button for toggling
> ```
>
> between fullscreen and embedded display modes.
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 3.2 and later.
>
> Declared in MPMoviePlayerController.h.
> ```
>
> MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen
>
> ```
> Controls for fullscreen playback are displayed. The controls include a start/pause button, a scrubber bar, forward and reverse
> ```
>
> seeking buttons, a button for toggling between fullscreen and embedded
>   display modes, a button for toggling the aspect fill mode, and a Done
>   button. Tapping the done button pauses the video and exits fullscreen
>   mode.
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 3.2 and later.
>
> Declared in MPMoviePlayerController.h.
> ```
>
> MPMovieControlStyleDefault
>
> ```
> Fullscreen controls are displayed by default.
>
> Available in iOS 3.2 and later.
>
> Declared in MPMoviePlayerController.h.
> ```

Refer [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks for response, but as you have mentioned above, if I will use MPMovieControlStyleNone, it will hide all controls and for sure I don't want to make that . Just I want hide the volume bar (same it displays on the simulator), do you another approach ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this except "hacking" the subviews. You may subclass MPMoviePlayerViewController and iterate the subviews. In one of my apps, I used code like this to remove things like the media controls:

```
- (void)removeMediaControls
{
    @try
    {
        // Search for the MPSwipeableView
        for (UIView *view1 in [self.view subviews])
        {
            // Check for the MPSwipeableView
            if ([[[view1 class] description] isEqualToString:@"MPSwipableView"])
            {
                // Search for the MPVideoBackgroundView
                for (UIView *view2 in [view1 subviews])
                {
                    // Check for the MPVideoBackgroundView
                    if ([[[view2 class] description] isEqualToString:@"MPVideoBackgroundView"])
                    {
                        // Search for the UIView
                        for (UIView *view3 in [view2 subviews])
                        {
                            // Check for the MPWildcatFullScreenVideoOverlay
                            if ([[[view3 class] description] isEqualToString:@"MPWildcatFullScreenVideoOverlay"])
                            {
                                // Search for the MPWildcatFullScreenNavigationBar
                                for (UIView *view4 in [view3 subviews])
                                {
                                    // Check for the UIImageView
                                    if ([[[view4 class] description] isEqualToString:@"UIImageView"])
                                    {
                                        // Remove the overlay
                                        [view4 removeFromSuperview];
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException * e)
    {

    }
}
```

The code above is too old, it worked with iOS 4.3. On iOS 5 and iOS 6 the view hierarchy changed, so you may have to updated your code with every new iOS version. See also: [MPMoviePlayerController hide volume slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159735/mpmovieplayercontroller-hide-volume-slider)

Comment: Thnx for response, regarding to the attached link, I have tried it but unfortunately it doesn't work, and Xcode show an error about MPVolumeSlider "symbol not found" ! I will try your code and come back

Comment: You have to do some reverse engeneering to find out the class names on iOS 5 or iOS 6, :-)